# HttpClient - Upload JAR file using Tomcat Webdav leads to "invalid or corrupt jarfile"

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, apache-httpclient-4.x, webdav

I can't manage to upload a JAR file, using Webdav and Apache HTTPClient without leading to "invalid or corrupt jarfile" when I attempt to launch it.

Here's my Setup:

- Webdav server, using tomcat 8.5 on an external directory (defined in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/webdav.xml)
- Apache HTTP Client (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.5)
- Custom Maven Plugin using HTTP Client to upload the file

File is uploaded using a custom maven plugin (which uses HTTP Client internally) after building the JAR.

If I try to use HTTP Client to upload the file to the remote server, it leads to corruption. But I can launch the Jar without any problemif I send the exact same file using curl command

`curl -u <user>:<pass> -T <myjar>.jar http://<remotehost>/<myjar>.jar`

Here is the sample code using HTTP Client:

```
class FileSender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // [...]
        RequestConfig.Builder cfg = RequestConfig.copy(RequestConfig.DEFAULT);
        cfg = cfg.setConnectTimeout(timeout)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(timeout);

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = authentication.credentials();
        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(cfg.build())
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
        try(CloseableHttpClient client = builder.build()) {
            HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut("http://<remote>/<myJar>.jar");
            httpPut.setEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addBinaryBody("file", new File("path/to/<myJar>.jar"))
                    .build());
            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPut)) {
                // Check response HTTP status
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any what might cause my issue ?

Edit: MD5 hashes seems different if I use HTTP Client and CURL, but CURL & FTP copy share the same hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing this

```
MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
           .addBinaryBody("file", new File("path/to/<myJar>.jar"))
           .build()
```

by this

```
new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/<myJar>.jar)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how you can upload any file with HttpClient:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

HttpEntity requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addBinaryBody("file", new File("myfile")).build();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://...");
post.setEntity(requestEntity);

try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post)) {
    System.out.print(response.getStatusLine());
}
```

Usually POST method is used to upload form or file content.